# Snap couldn't remove package and cannot abort changes

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, snap, steam

I have wanted to remove "steam" from snap so I started with `snap list` and I got:

```
Name                    Version          Rev    Tracking            Publisher   Notes
bare                    1.0              5      latest/stable       canonical✓  base
core                    16-2.59.5        15511  latest/stable       canonical✓  core
core20                  20230622         1974   latest/stable       canonical✓  base
core22                  20230612         766    latest/stable       canonical✓  base
firefox                 115.0-2          2850   latest/stable/…     mozilla✓    -
gaming-graphics-core22  23.1.2~kisak1~j  76     kisak-fresh/stable  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004         0+git.6f39565    140    latest/stable/…     canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204           0+git.ff35a85    120    latest/stable       canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-81-g442e511  1535   latest/stable/…     canonical✓  -
snapd                   2.59.5           19457  latest/stable       canonical✓  snapd
steam                   1.0.0.76         146    latest/stable       canonical✓  -
viber-unofficial        0.1              37     latest/stable       uglide      -
```

Then I did snap remove `snap remove steam`, but it stucks on this:

`Save data of snap "steam" in automatic snapshot set #1` After some time I tried to restart PC, to turn it off and so on, after that I tried 2-3 times to do the same, with same result, it just stuck on that.

Then I tried to see what happened with snap so I did `snap changes` and got this:

```
ID   Status  Spawn                    Ready                    Summary
36   Error   yesterday at 21:38 EEST  yesterday at 21:44 EEST  Remove "steam" snap
37   Error   yesterday at 21:44 EEST  yesterday at 22:07 EEST  Remove "steam" snap
38   Done    yesterday at 21:44 EEST  yesterday at 21:45 EEST  Auto-refresh snaps "firefox", "gnome-42-2204"
39   Error   yesterday at 22:10 EEST  yesterday at 22:33 EEST  Remove "steam" snap
```

So I tried to abort them with `sudo snap abort 36` (or any other number) but I got:

```
error: cannot abort change 36 with nothing pending
```

So .. right now I'm stucked on it, Cannot remove steam, cannot abort actions, nothing .. If I try to remove steam it just stuck again and create new snap changes...

Comment: It's creating a snapshot of your data in case you need it when reinstalling that package again later ... It can take a long time with some packages, but you can skip it with `sudo snap remove --purge steam`

Answer (score 1):

the `snap changes` is just a log in history, if there is nothing in state "doing" currently, you have nothing to abort and you should be able to remove or install. I had the same problem, and even after I restarted the PC I found one change in state "doing" so I just aborted this one instead of the "error" one